# How do I crop multiple areas of each frame of the video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, linux

For each frame I want to crop multiple areas using ffmpeg but I am not sure how to proceed.

This is what I have done to crop one part of the image,

```
fmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter:v "fps=1,crop=759:41:33:99,scale=128:44" %d.png
```

This is one frame of the video,

[image]

The above command crops the number one row or first position from the image. Likewise I want to crop all the positions or rows from this frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more outputs.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter:v "fps=1,crop=759:41:33:99,scale=128:44" row1-%d.png -filter:v "fps=1,crop=759:41:33:140,scale=128:44" row2-%d.png -filter:v "fps=1,crop=759:41:33:181,scale=128:44" row3-%d.png
```

Or do one row per command.